# How to remove an sprite when game is over?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have been stuck in this part, I have been trying to removeFromParent but it doesnt work. In my game when an enemy colide 3 times with the player the game is over, the problem is that the enemies continue coming for some seconds and then dissapear but continue makeing damage to the player.

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let body1 = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
    let body2 = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode

    if ((body1.name == "circuloPrincipal") && (body2.name == "enemigo")) {

       colisionPrincipal(body2)



    }else {

       ((body1.name == "enemigo") && (body2.name == "circuloPrincipal"))

       colisionPrincipal(body1)


    }


}




func colisionPrincipal(enemigo: SKSpriteNode) {


        if hits < 2 && circuloPrincipal.color != enemigo.color{

       shakeFrame(scene!)

            circuloPrincipal.runAction(SKAction.scaleBy(1.5, duration:0.5))

           enemigo.removeFromParent()

             let particula = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "particulas.sks")

            particula?.position = enemigo.position
            particula?.hidden = false

            particula?.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.8))


          self.addChild(particula!)

            hits += 1


        }else if circuloPrincipal.color == enemigo.color {

            enemigo.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

            enemigo.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

            enemigo.removeFromParent()

         score += 1

            scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"


        }else {

            shakeFrame(scene!)

            gameStarted = false

            enemigo.removeFromParent()
            enemigoTimer.invalidate()

            highscoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.5))


            if score > highscore {

               let highscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

                highscore = score

                highscoreDefault.setInteger(highscore, forKey: "highscore")

                highscoreLabel.text = "Best: \(highscore)"

            }

    }

}
```

Comment: You're not really giving us much to work on. Where is the above function called from? The logical thing would be to have something like a `gameOver` variable (it that perhaps your gameStarted var?) Then when this is true just return from the didBeginContact function without doing any checks of performing any logic.

Comment: I added the did Begin contact code to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I don't have all that much information about your game to go by, but if you don't want the enemies to keep damaging the player the quick and dirty fix would be to add a guard to the top of your didBeginContact function:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    guard hits < 3 else {
        return
    }
    let body1 = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
    let body2 = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode

    if ((body1.name == "circuloPrincipal") && (body2.name == "enemigo")) {
       colisionPrincipal(body2)
    }else {
       ((body1.name == "enemigo") && (body2.name == "circuloPrincipal"))
       colisionPrincipal(body1)
    }
}
```

This should at least prevent anything to get called based on contacts after the required number of hits have occurred. As for cleaning up the sprites, this sounds rather simple (removeFromParent at the appropriate time) but I haven't got a clue about how you handle your game-states so it's hard to comment any further.

Personally I'd trigger it from the `update()` function if the required state has happened...

Comment: I added Benjamin Thanks btw, but now the enemies doesnt make ny damage

Comment: If you add your existing code where it says this should work identically to what you have until the point when your hits variable has reached 3. After this point the enemies will not make any damage (as intended, I figured?)

Comment: OK, I've added the bits that I figured you could add yourself for clarity.

Comment: It worked Benjamin! the only problem now is that now the game never ends